# Convert list into data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have read a html table with

```
tables <- readHTMLTable(path, which=1)
```

and would like to process the information further. Currently my data looks like this.

```
Category Entry
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
A 7
B 8
C 9
```

I would like to have a data frame that looks like this.

```
A B C
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `unstack`

```
unstack(df1, Entry~Category)
#  A B C
#1 1 2 3
#2 4 5 6
#3 7 8 9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C"), Entry = 1:9), .Names = c("Category", "Entry"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: My result looks different. The result appeasrs in rows instead of columns `$PY
     [1] "1995" "1994" "1998" "1969" "1988" "1987"`

Comment: @PeterGerft My output is based on the input you showed and it is giving the expected output you showed.